# In React a Material UI Textfield does not update or reset to placeholder value once a value is set on conditional render

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

In a React project, I am rendering a material-ui `TextField` component which is supposed to render conditionally different things.

Lets say in a component `A` there is a state `name` with default value `""` and the `TextField` for that should have a `placeholder` property with value `Enter name`. If the state `name` has anything else other than `""` then the `TextField` should not have `placeholder` but instead should show the `name` value in its `value` property.

I was able to achieve this behavior by rendering the `TextField` conditionally but once the the `TextField` with `name` value is rendered, even if the `name` state becomes `""` the `Textfield` with the `placeholder` property does not render.

```
import { Box, TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const A= () => {
const [name, setName] = useState("");

const handleFieldChange = (value) => {
  setName(value);
};

const clearName = () => { setName("") }
console.log(name)

return (
<Box flex={1}>
  <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
    {name === "" ? (
      <TextField
        id="filled-basic"
        hiddenLabel
        size="small"
        variant="filled"
        width="100%"
        placeholder="Enter name"
        onChange={(e) => {
          handleFieldChange(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    ) : (<TextField
      id="filled-basic"
      hiddenLabel
      size="small"
      variant="filled"
      width="100%"
      value={name}
      onChange={(e) => {
        handleFieldChange(e.target.value);
      }}
    />)}
  </Box>
  <Button onClick={clearName}> Clear </Button>
</Box>
);
};

export default A;
```

So in the above code example, when the `Clear` button is clicked the `TextField` with placeholder property should render but instead it renders the old `TextField` with previous value.

Comment: @Titus this code was for reference so I have updated it as per your comment but I get your point. In my use case there is an object in a state and the condition is on one of that object's property. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Even though I don't know why you will want to do this since just one `TextField` with a placeholder will provide the same functionality, this seems to work as expected, here it is in action https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-hertz-rvb00c?file=/src/A.js

Comment: @Titus I appreciate the codesandbox link but it doesn't work as expected. I clicked on the clear button and it does not clear the TextField and not showing the placeholder again. Can you please check and confirm once? I want the placeholder back once the name is ""

Comment: Oh, I see, that is because the first `TextField` is uncontrolled, the input's value is not set by the state of the component. If you want to make this work (even though I don't see any reason for it), you'll have to keep a reference (using `useRef`) to the `TextFiled`'s `input` element and clear it's value when the `name` state variable is set to `""`.

Comment: Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-hertz-rvb00c?file=/src/A.js